# Why the second time iterating on large number of bytes is significantly slower? And how to fix it?

Tags: c++, performance

This code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Test( ) {
#define current_milliseconds std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( std::chrono::system_clock::now( ).time_since_epoch( ) ).count( )
    int *c = ( int* )malloc( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 );
    int result = 0;
    auto millis = -current_milliseconds;
    //clock_t timer = -clock( );
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1024 * 1024 * 256 /* 1024 / 4 */; ++i )
        result += c[ i ];
    millis += current_milliseconds;
    printf( "Took: %ldms (JUST PASSING BY: %d)\n", millis, result );
    free( c );
#undef current_milliseconds
}

int main( ) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1 ) );
    Test( );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1 ) );
    Test( );
    return -1;
}
```

I ran 7 tests and gave the last 6 outputs:

```
Took: 502ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 607ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 480ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 588ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 492ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 562ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 506ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 558ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 470ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 555ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 510ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 562ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
```

If your output is different, then try to run the executable again (Hard-disk cache misses) or try to enlarge the number of iterations and allocated bytes (Have a feeling).

Notice that the timer's code range is only on the loop and not the allocation too; then there goes the question again: why the second iteration is slower? Is there a way to fix it?

Additional Information:

1. That PC has pentium 2.8GHZ @ 2 cores (Intel E6300) processor, 4GB RAM (had 2.2GB free RAM before executing the tests), and enterprise Intel SSD.
2. It seem that while executing the tests, it wrote a few of 100MBs. Why it did when it had enough free RAM? (I deallocated 1GB and then allocated another 1GB, it shouldn't pass pre-swapfile it)

Comment: It ran faster on my machine (Visual C++ 2013 Core i7) and on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff900dc589d7cf08  Also, clock() is not accurate anyway.  Use std::chrono instead.

Comment: @MobyDisk Thanks for taking the time to test; my test ran on Pentium E6300 CPU. I will try to change from `clock` to `std::chrono`.

Comment: @MobyDisk, what are you basing that on? The standard `std::chrono` clocks measure wall time, which means they will report your program running slower if the machine is busy. `clock()` reports CPU time, which is only the time spent running your process and not other tasks on the same machine. So `clock()` is better for timing code unless you have a completely idle machine.

Comment: Just one run is not enough.  Please post the results of more runs.  Better yet, please post the average and standard deviation of many runs.

Comment: @MikeNakis I ran it enough times to say that the first is always faster than the second. (I will re-write it to implement average)

Comment: @MikeNakis Wait how to make average out of it? I will need to re-run the process ten times and write all the results and then do with it things. I can't just post it here

Comment: No, ***do not run the process many times***, run your benchmark in a loop and collect results, all in the same process.  Standard deviation is important too.  When the standard deviation is low, you know you have a good average. When it is high, you know that the average is meaningless.

Comment: Also, is there any specific reason why you are using the system clock instead of the high resolution clock?

Comment: @MikeNakis I can't... This behaviour only occurring after running this test twice, after the second time it's the same. You forgot you read something.

Comment: What's with the horrible marcos?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "This behaviour only occurring after running this test twice, after the second time it's the same." What is the same?  The same as what?

Comment: Try taking a look at the assembly that was generated. I'm wondering if that function call got optimized out and the 2nd call has slightly different assembly instructions.

Comment: @MikeNakis When you open the process and then do the test it's faster than after you re-run the test on that process. If you will re-run the test a lot of times and make average out of those tests you won't get any reliable results.

Comment: I get very consistent results on ideone, too: http://ideone.com/NkaaRh  So, I am afraid there is something funny going on with your machine.

Comment: @NeilKirk macro* what's horrible about it? (While it is out of context)

Comment: @MikeNakis Try running it on your machine maybe? On the first try of executing this program I have weird results too.

Comment: @MahlerFive Mostly optimized out is when there is zero time between the timers or the result of the timer is the time taken to fetch the current time. Anyway it can't be optimized out, look at `printf` parameters.

Comment: Well then, your methodology is wrong.  First you have to get consistent results on the same run, and *then* you might have an issue to discuss.  As it is right now, you have a weird thing that only happens under certain weird circumstances on your weird machine, and this is of no interest to anyone.  I would suggest, not even to you.

Comment: This benchmark doesn't test code performance at all.  It tests how quickly your operating system can deal with page faults and map virtual memory to RAM.

Comment: If someone creates a function or variable called `current_milliseconds` after your Test function, it will break. You never undef it. I think you tried to, but made a typo. Which shows the problems with macros even more.

Comment: @HansPassant This can be made into an answer? Or is there a principle in benchmarking that I didn't follow that made me do a mistake?

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for pointing out my mistake. This is a CPP file so it will never go through another file (Unless you made a mistake.), and if you did create a function, then you should check whatever something exists with such name. (Basic step)

Comment: Why should you check? Are you really saying every single time I define a local variable, I should search the project for a macro? That defeats the point of namespaces and scope.

Comment: @NeilKirk Not every single time, but you should know your project or at least what are you including. Anyway, you are over-exaggerating. This is small test, I wanted it to be really small, but meaningful enough. I am not macro lover nor hater.

Comment: Do you still have a difference when you start initializing your *c with memset()` ? Do you still have a difference when you make *c static and only initialize it the first time?

Comment: As someone who needed to rename some variables in a project because of someone else's stupid use of macros, I'm not exaggerating. If you are going to use macros, at least follow the convention of making them all upper case.

Comment: @WalterA Not sure why I am not surprised, but no, there's no difference. By the way I think the memory are initialized to zero in the first place. (It's large allocation)

Comment: @NeilKirk Your IDE can't show you that you have macros? Or you just ignored it which is bad.

Comment: No, a new bad header file is included in the project which defines macros that are used as function names elsewhere..

Comment: I wonder: Is the free() command starting something on the background and is the system overhead freeíng everything the cause?
Can you add a sleep of 2 seconds before your second Test() ?

Comment: @NeilKirk I will never do something as evil as this, but still the IDE will tell you that you use the macro and not the function (at least in VS), which is obvious.

Comment: @WalterA But if I am sharing the allocation between the two tests the results are still the same doesn't it means that it doesn't matter?

Comment: I don't want the IDE to tell me, I want to include a new header file without breaking existing code.

Comment: Your first test starts when our system is happy and quiet. During your first Test() other programs are swapped to disk, fighting for small slices of memory. When the first Test() is finished, the system is hard working on recovery from those hundreds of msecs misery. The programs are not completely recovered yet and there you have the second attack ! At the start of the second Test() the system is in another state than when you started the first one. When you start 2 instances of your program in different windows, I expect both instances will show worse performance.

Comment: is overall optimization is ok or just fixing to this specific problem?

Comment: What are your system's specs, in particular concerning free RAM before starting the test program. This is required to verify @WalterA's explanation. That said, the macro that generated so much heat here could have been implemented using a simple function.

Comment: @WalterA I will try in a few minutes. (Make the sleep longer)

Comment: @DavidHaim Actually it slows the whole program down if you meant that. The Optimization is of course on.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt (Remember it from before) It had 2.2GB~ free RAM. I used `clock` and it was the same. The CPU is 2.8GHZ Pentium E6300, and 4GB of RAM in total.

Comment: @WalterA I just tried it (3s of sleep) and the first and the second  tests had the same exactly time (421ms) every execution. It's weird, I had 2GB of free RAM, I have SSD here, if it should touch my SSD then it's already fast. It won't throw 2GB to the SSD, maybe a bit and still it will be loaded and stored fast enough to be unnoticeable. I will try to confirm this.

Comment: Can you profile to see where time is spent? One guess could be that it is related to the kernel zeroing memory before giving it to the application.

Comment: @MarcGlisse The time I check is on the loop not allocation, which can zero the memory.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky This is done lazily by the kernel, pages are only allocated when you access them (usually when you write to them, actually, the system might only give you one single copy-on-write page in your program).

Comment: Just wondering, but weren't there some tweaks in the Linux scheduler to improve latency of interactive applications? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/index.html indicates that the first time through your loop your application might still be considered as IO-bound (low virtual runtime), while after that loop it's clear that it is CPU-bound (to be precise, it's probably RAM-bandwidth bound). The fact that sleeping helps again indicates that the kernel then places the task back into the IO-bound category, which speeds up the immediately following loop.

Comment: Ran faster second time on my PC too.  233ms v 227ms.  Though I would rate those roughly equal given mysteries of whatever the processor happens to being doing at that moment.

Comment: @Robinson Try running this a few times, not just one time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Output on my machine:

> Took: 371ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
>   Took: 318ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Somewhat more typical for what I expect most programmers to see when they try your program.  You can make a small change to get a vastly different outcome:

```
int *c = (int*)malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
memset(c, 0, 1024 * 1024 * 1024);          // <== added
// etc..
```

Which produces on my machine:

> Took: 104ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
>   Took: 102ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

A fat x3 speed-up, just from initializing the memory content.  Hope it reproduces on your machine, it should.  First conclusion that you need to draw is that you've been bench-marking something *completely* different than the cost of your code.  A very typical benchmark hazard on modern machines.

This is the behavior of a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  Like Windows, Linux or OSX.  Your malloc() call never actually allocated any memory, it merely *reserved address space*.  Just numbers to the processor, there is one for each 4096 bytes of memory.  You don't pay the cost of using memory until later, when you actually address it.  When the *demand-paged* feature comes into play.

Which happens in your `result += c[ i ];` statement.  At that point the pedal must meet the metal and the operating system is forced to actually make the memory available.  Every 4096 bytes your program generates a *page fault*.  The operating system steps in and maps 4096 bytes of RAM to the virtual memory page.  Your program generates 1GB / 4096 = 262,144 of those page faults.  You can conclude that your operating system requires roughly 400ms/262144 ~= 1.5 microseconds to handle a page fault.  Mine is about twice as fast at it.

Note how the memset() call *hid* that cost, it generated all those page faults *before* you started to time the code execution.  Thus truly measuring the cost of the code and avoiding the otherwise inevitable initialization overhead.

How long your first run takes is going to depend on how quickly the operating system can make the RAM available.  Actual measurement can vary greatly from one try to the next, it depends on how many other processes have mapped RAM pages.  Might take quite a while if the OS needs to find space and unmap pages first, preserving their content in the paging file.

How long the second run takes is going to depend on how quickly the operating system can recycle the RAM pages if there are not enough of them available to map another gigabyte.  Not much of problem on mine, I have 8 GB of RAM and using only 5.6 of it right now.  They need to be zero-initialized, a low priority duty on a typical OS.

So, basic conclusion here:

- You are measuring an *initialization* cost, it is not at all representative for how your program is going to be affected while it continues to use the memory.  Your benchmark, as-is, doesn't tell you anything.
- The difference you observed is an operating system implementation detail, it doesn't have anything to do with your program.

Comment: At least on Linux, malloc allocates large chunks using mmap. When free is called it calls munmap. On the second iteration it does mmap again, hence you do not observe any caching effects between the runs. While you are correct about the mechanics of demand paging, this does not explain the difference in timings the OP is asking about.

Comment: I am a bit of confused too like @MaximEgorushkin , because I had 2.2GB of free memory, and it wrote quiet a few of 100MBs.

Comment: The only thing I know for a fact is that I don't have the same operating system as you do.  Whatever it might be.  I'm trying *really* hard to not make this a pissing match about what operating system is "better", that never turns out well.  Get rid of the initialization artifacts from your benchmark results, only sane way to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant how does malloc handle large allocation requests on your platform? My point is that you get the same number of page faults on subsequent runs.

Comment: I would expect some systems to use COW and never have any page fault in the OP's example, since he never writes. Though that's probably not the case if memset makes the program faster...

Comment: @MarcGlisse This is how Linux works, see http://lwn.net/Articles/517465/. Although you still get page faults which cause the zero page to be mapped.

Comment: Re-read this. Your hypothesis does not explain the observed different timings of the loops and there is no supporting evidence. I provided supporting evidence for my answer, so you may like to check it out.

Comment: `How long the second run takes is going to depend on how quickly the operating system can recycle the RAM pages if there are not enough of them available to map another gigabyte`, I had 2.2GB free RAM before running this. It should have another 200MB free. Maybe because of this the first time I run my executable my test is a bit weird? (See the question, I hided the first two-tests) --- this is the only thing that stops me from accepting, but the fixing part is OK.

Comment: That's just not enough, the other processes, operating system, drivers and file system cache need RAM as well.  You can't assume that they can survive on 200 MB and keep your machine responsive.  You'll always invoke the recycle delays.  Buying more RAM is always a good investment btw, it is dirt-cheap these days.  8 GB sets you back only 80 bucks.

Comment: @HansPassant But the process never actually took 2GB, I allocated deallocated and then allocated, shouldn't it use the 1GB from before and not overriding system's memory?

Comment: What, what?? Did you buy the RAM yet?  I'm not going to speculate how quickly your OS can recycle pages, you already know.  You measured it.

Answer (score 2):

Your time measurements look inconsistent because there is too much variance in time. It looks like the CPU may be switching frequencies while you run your benchmarks.

Try disabling the CPU frequency scaling when running the benchmarks. In Windows you can do that by setting Performance profile in Power Management in the Control Panel, that locks the CPU frequency on its highest.

---

Let's test this hypothesis.

Here are my results of your benchmark on Linux with the default `powersave` governor, they are similar to yours in respect to high timing variance:

```
[max@localhost:~/src/test] $ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 5.70 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 5.70 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.26 GHz.
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores

[max@localhost:~/src/test] $ for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do ./test; echo; done
Took: 698ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 598ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 541ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 570ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 660ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 656ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 673ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 616ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 637ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 650ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 690ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 667ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 671ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 603ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 537ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 544ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 535ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 629ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 660ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 656ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
```

And here are the result with `performance` governor, notice how little variance there is in timings this time:

```
[max@localhost:~/src/test] $ sudo cpupower frequency-set --related --governor performance
Setting cpu: 0
Setting cpu: 1
Setting cpu: 2
Setting cpu: 3
Setting cpu: 4
Setting cpu: 5
Setting cpu: 6
Setting cpu: 7

[max@localhost:~/src/test] $ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 5.70 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 5.70 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 4.34 GHz.
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores

[max@localhost:~/src/test] $ for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do ./test; echo; done
Took: 539ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 548ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 543ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 547ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 542ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 543ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 548ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 539ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 538ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 536ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 536ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 536ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 546ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 547ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 559ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 534ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 537ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 540ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 538ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 534ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
```

It shows that it takes the same time to execute both loops, neither loop is faster.

Comment: It was on high performance from before. I am not sure whatever I like the idea of it being turned to non-programming context. :(

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I could not understand you, could you rephrase it please?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I have demonstrated that your code works as expected, there is little variance in my timings, while your timings show a lot of variance. It means that your PC does not execute the code as fast as it should and I told you the most likely reason. Alternatively, your PC is under heavy load or misconfigured.

Comment: My PC is a toaster, except that it has SSD.

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing pages for the first time on that first lap, and that's going quicker than the second, so whatever memory management your OS does on a freshly-allocated gigabyte is cheaper the first time.

If your OS maps newly-allocated storage to a page full of zeros and maps newly-referenced memory to its own page on access rather than on write, and it doesn't map a gigabyte allocation to the big 2M pages then the second lap through your gigabyte you'll be TLB missing pretty much every 4K.  That can get ... not cheap.

So I'm thinking that whatever your OS is doing to map a newly-referenced page might be faster than a full TLB miss.  That would easily happen if, for instance, PTEs are cacheable and every time the OS allocates a new bottom-level table it clears it, allowing your  TLB misses to reload from pre-primed cache lines, recently initialized on-chip, where by the second lap your serial misses would have long since flushed the entries and the CPU has to fetch them over that long, long bus (which at this level of concern might better be viewed as a network connection).

I don't know the x86 performance counters or tools to check them, but if you've got access to decent tooling it should be easy to check theories by looking at the right counter deltas.

Comment: There is likely no reuse of memory on the second run.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  I'm talking about PTE initialization. I'd think an OS is at any rate less likely to reclaim PTE allocations than to take released storage from a process in the absence of memory pressure.  It might be useful to get people's exact chip models -- but that still leaves us in theoryland, and looking at the counters will tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

(rewrite after comment)

The second time iterating is significant slower because the load on the system is different. The first Test is running in a normal situation, the second run is when the first run has just finished.
Other programs on the system are still recovering/swapping/logging after the fight for resources when the second Test is started.
When you want to compare two Tests, give the system some time to return to a normal state before launching the second test.
A simple method is adding a sleep of a few seconds after the first Test().

This solution was already discussed in the comment.
LyingOnTheSky confirmed that adding a sleep of 3 sec solved the mystery:
The first and the second tests had exactly the same time (421ms) for the execution.

Comment: My computer is just old, except that it has SSD which is modern. I think you need to re-write it to make it an answer. (You don't need to leave evidence, just write a note at the end that the source is from the comments.)

Comment: I am still doubting this, the reason -> there is no need to use the swapfile because I had 2.2GB free RAM, and I allocated 1GB deallocated it and then allocated again, I didn't commit more RAM than I had. Maybe need clearer explanation there.

Comment: I do not know which resources gave the problem, you could try monitoring with tools like iostat/vmstat. Many years ago an OS lowered the priority of my program that used a lot of CPU. I just stated that the sitiuation for the first and second test were different, as proved by your statistics. Other answers here might be the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Took: 682ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 666ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 686ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 680ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 674ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 675ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 694ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 684ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
```

In my workstation takes the same time or even less for the second test. If you know the memory layout of the problem you can always use internal builtins to prefetch memory.

```
 __builtin_prefetch
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: Does prefetch works in the background, or it yields until it fetches that cache-line? I've always wondered.

Answer (score 0):

as already explained by the other people, basically you are experiencing a sort of bias (initialisation cost + OS + other hardware dependent operations that you can't control).

All results are workstation dependent (CPU + RAM + OS). For instance, my results are always close for the 1st and 2nd run (tested with and without optimisation, see later).

Just a curiosity. Instead of call `Test()` only 2 times, try to call it 10 or 15 in your code. You should start to see more close results.

As last thing, I don't know if you are trying to evaluate the performance of your code looking at the time execution. If yes, please consider to use a better tools like `valgrind` or `gprof`.
With valgrind, you can use `callgrind` to get an estimate of the number of executed instructions and hardware performance (is possible pass options to simulate **cache missing**, **branch prediction**, **hardware prefetcher**, ecc.):

```
 valgrind --tool=callgrind --cache-sim=yes --branch-sim=yes YOUR_PROGRAM
```

Executed on Apple MB Pro late 2014:

```
Took: 914ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 911ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 917ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 913ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 910ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 916ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 914ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 907ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 387ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 387ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 380ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 387ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 384ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 382ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)

Took: 380ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
Took: 381ms (JUST PASSING BY: 0)
```